# how to get db values without using an loop with wpdb->get_results()

Tags: wpdb

So I want to return the data from 1 row from my custom DB table, but I dont want to use a loop as I only need the values once....so is there a way to do this?

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE the_id = %d", $id));

$results->the_id;//not working
$results->the_name;//not working
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `get_row`.  Per the Codex:

> Get all the information about Link 10.
>
> ```
> $mylink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->links WHERE link_id = 10");
> ```
>
> The properties of the $mylink object are the column names of the
>   result from the SQL query (in this example all the columns from the
>   $wpdb->links table, but you could also query for specific columns
>   only).
>
> ```
> echo $mylink->link_id; // prints "10"
> ```
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row